# EclipseLink's @OrderCorrection has no effect on order index column

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, payara

I'm trying to use EclipseLink's `@OrderCorrection` to ensure correct order indexing for existing data, but it's no re-indexing the records when saving.

- Read the data database
- Saving root entity (A)
- No changes to existing entities occur

Even when adding a new element to the list to "force" a change, existing `null` remain `null`.  The new element is correctly indexed, though.

I'm running on Payara `4.1.2.181`, which used EclipseLink `2.6.4`.

```java
@Entity
public class A {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a", orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderColumn(name = "ORDERINDEX_PA")
    @OrderCorrection(OrderCorrectionType.READ_WRITE)
    private List<B> bList;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class B {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private A a;

}
```

Sample data:

[image]

Comment: "No changes to existing entities occur" - if nothing changes, EclipseLink doesn't do any updates. You need to change something on A for it to check the list to perform any index writes. I'm not sure where the null index values appear in your list pre/post list modification, maybe you can post more detail on what the list looks like before and after to explain why EclipseLink might not be reindexing the list.

Comment: Are you saying a change on object A is the only way to trigger a rewrite of object B order index?

Comment: That is what the docs state. I don't use this functionality myself as I don't want an application arbitrarily changing my data at runtime or run more then what my process meant to change.